# Javascript: Recursion Problem --> Return the longest key value in a deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested, key

Below is the problem:

// Get Longest Name

// Write a function, getLongestName, that takes an object. The object represents a family tree. Return the longest name in the family.

This is the code but it is returning an error:

```
let family = {
  'Beverly Marquez': {
    'Nina Rhone': {
      'William Rhodes': null,
      'Paul Nell': null,
      'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire': null
    }
  }
};


function getLongestName (family){

  let longestName = ''; 

  for (let key in family){
    let value = family[key]
    console.log(value)

    if (typeof value === 'object'){
      let descendentLongestName = getLongestName (value)
    }

    else {
      descendentLongestName = value
    }

    if (descendentLongestName.length > longestName.length){
      let longestName = descendentLongestName
    }
  }
  return longestName; 
}


getLongestName(family); // => 'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire'
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error: ReferenceError: descendentLongestName is not defined

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to declare `descendentLongestName` where you declare `longestName` instead of inside the `if` block. And you don't need `let` in that last `if` because `longestName` is already declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your code, but I'd like to suggest a new solution.

The idea is to decompose your problem into two parts:

- find all keys from a nested object, recursively
- find the longest one from an array of strings

```js
let longest = ary => ary
    .reduce((max, x) =>
        x.length > max.length ? x : max, '');

let allKeys = obj => obj
    ? Object.keys(obj).concat(
        ...Object.values(obj).map(allKeys))
    : [];

//

let family = {
    'Beverly Marquez': {
        'Nina Rhone': {
            'William Rhodes': null,
            'Paul Nell': null,
            'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire': null,
        }
    }
};

console.log(longest(allKeys(family)));
```

Comment: `sort()` mutates the array. It may be advisable to shallow copy it first. e.g. `[...ary].sort(/*...*/)`

Comment: @customcommander: yep, I've replaced `longest` with a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

let scope is block specific so 
if you want to use it then declare it outside of block otherwise use var

```
function getLongestName (family){

  let longestName = ''; 

  for (let key in family){
    let value = family[key]
    console.log(value)
let descendentLongestName='';
    if (typeof value === 'object'){
      descendentLongestName = getLongestName (value)
    }

    else {
      descendentLongestName = value
    }
let longestName;
    if (descendentLongestName && descendentLongestName.length > longestName.length){
     longestName = descendentLongestName
    }
  }
  return longestName; 
}
```

Comment: when I run your code above, getLongestName(family) returns ' '

Answer (score 0):

You could use two parts, one for checking the key and a recursive part for getting the keys of the the nested objects.

```js
function getLongestKey(object, keys = []) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce((r, k) => {
        if (!r || r[0].length < k.length) {
            r = [k];
        } else if (r[0].length === k.length) {
            r.push(k);
        }
        return object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object'
            ? getLongestKey(object[k], r)
            : r;
    }, undefined)

}

let family = { 'Beverly Marquez': { 'Nina Rhone': { 'William Rhodes': null, 'Paul Nell': null, 'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire': null } } };

console.log(getLongestKey(family));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a key and its value can be competing for having the longest string, it might make sense to use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in a recursive function:

```js
var family = {
    'Beverly Marquez': {
        'Nina Rhone': {
            'William Rhodes': null,
            'Paul Nell': null,
            'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire': null,
        }
    }
};

const longest = (obj, cur = '') =>
    Object.entries(obj).reduce((max, [key, val]) => {
        const candidate = (val && longest(val, max)) || key;
        return candidate.length > max.length ? candidate : max; }, cur);
        
      
console.log(longest(family));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for...in` loop to loop through the key-value pairs in the `family` object. If the value is an object, use recursion to loop through that object, to see if the key of that object is longer than any of the keys before it. Return the longest key (name).

```js
function getLongestName(family) {
  let longest = "";
  for (let key in family) {

    //create initial longest
    if (key.length > longest.length) {
      longest = key;
    } 

    let value = family[key];
    
    //if value is an object
    if (typeof value === "object") {
      //use recursion to get the key-values of that value
      let descendant = getLongestName(value);

      //if descendant's name is longer than longest, assign it to 'longest'
      if (descendant.length > longest.length) {
        longest = descendant;
      }
    } 
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(getLongestName(family));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a simple function `traverse` -

```
const traverse = function* (t = {})
{ if (t == null) return
  for (const [ name, children ] of Object.entries(t))
  { yield name
    yield* traverse(children)
  }
}

console.log(Array.from(traverse(family)))
// [ "Beverly Marquez"
// , "Nina Rhone"
// , "William Rhodes"
// , "Paul Nell"
// , "Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire"
// ]
```

This separates the traversal of your tree from the operation you wish to perform on the values of the tree. Now we implement a simple `longestName` function -

```
const longestName = (t = {}) =>
{ let r = ""
  for (const name of traverse(t))
    if (name.length > r.length)
      r = name
  return r
}

console.log(longestName(family))
// Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire
```

As you can see, writing `longestName` is easy now that we don't have to concern ourselves with traversal logic at the same time.

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
let family = {
  'Beverly Marquez': {
    'Nina Rhone': {
      'William Rhodes': null,
      'Paul Nell': null,
      'Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire': null
    }
  }
}

const traverse = function* (t = {})
{ if (t == null) return
  for (const [ name, children ] of Object.entries(t))
    { yield name
      yield* traverse(children)
    }
}

const longestName = (t = {}) =>
{ let r = ""
  for (const name of traverse(t))
    if (name.length > r.length)
      r = name
  return r
}

console.log(longestName(family))
// Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire

console.log(Array.from(traverse(family)))
// [ "Beverly Marquez"
// , "Nina Rhone"
// , "William Rhodes"
// , "Paul Nell"
// , "Sir Paddington the Fourth, of the county Wilstonshire"
// ]
```

---

If there was other data in the tree, you can see how it would be easy to write other functions using `traverse` as well -

```js
const myTree =
  { name: "Alice"
  , gender: "F"
  , children:
      [ { name: "Bob"
        , gender: "M"
        , children:
            [ { name: "Charles"
              , gender: "M"
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }

const traverse = function* ({ children = [], ...t })
{ yield t
  for (const child of children)
    yield* traverse(child)
}

const filter = function* (test, t = {})
{ for (const leaf of traverse(t))
    if (test(leaf))
      yield leaf
}

const byGender = (q = "", t = {}) =>
  filter(node => node.gender === q, t)

console.log(Array.from(byGender("M", myTree)))
// [ { name: "Bob", gender: "M" }, { name: "Charles", gender: "M" } ]

console.log(Array.from(byGender("F", myTree)))
// [ { name: "Alice", gender: "F" } ]
```